# Find which permissions can be updateable in Permission Set

Tags: permission-sets

I have created a Permission Set and assigned a salesforce license. When i call api `url/PermissionSet/{id}`. It gives me list of permissions that are either true or false.
Now There are few permissions that I want to update like `
***PermissionsIsContactCenterSupervisor*** or ***PermissionsIsotopeCToCUser***
These permissions are not updating once I hit patch call from http client.

So my question is Do we have any API or SOQL that let us know that there are few permissions that you can't update it  ?

Thanks

Comment: Check if `PermissionSet.IsCustom` is true because there may be some standard permsets which you might not be able to update.

Comment: `PermissionSet.IsCustom` is true but I need to know which permissions in PermissionSet can be updateable.

Answer (score 0):

Use query `SELECT Id,Name,PermissionsIsotopeCToCUser FROM PermissionSet` in workbench and search for desired permission Eg. 'PermissionsIsotopeCToCUser' and set value from false to true and click **update** to check if it can be updated or no.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can do that but it's going to be manual operation against each permission to find out whether that particular permission can be updateable or not.

Comment: I don't think we have any documentation or api's which has list of permission which talks about DML operations